# Proving $ f:(0,1)\to R$ is uniformly continuous, where$ f(x)=1/(x+4)$ for all $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: analysis, functions, uniform-continuity

I am not sure how to choose delta with regards to epsilon in this question. In my scratch work i get to $\frac{|y-x|}{(x+4)(y+4)}$, and i dont know what to set this <= ? Hope someone can help!

Comment: Have you already learned the [Heine-Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine–Cantor_theorem) or the fact that every Lipschitz map is uniformly continuous ?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540090/find-a-function-that-is-continuous-on-0-1-but-not-uniformly-continuous-on-t/2540103#2540103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\delta = \varepsilon /16$. Then we have:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|={|y-x|\over (x+4)(y+4)}< {1\over 16}|x-y| = \varepsilon$$

since $4<x+4<5$ so ${1\over 5}< {1\over x+4}< {1\over 4}$